# How to integrate PayPal subscription in flutter?

Tags: flutter, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

Hello all I have searched all over the internet and found one article which shows how to integrate PayPal. But I need **how to implement subscription in PayPal** like I have some packages and I want that users subscribe for it on monthly basis and subscribe it through paying in PayPal. So, need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [braintree_payment package](https://pub.dev/packages/braintree_payment) to integrate PayPal in your app.

Comment: bro I know that but that don't provide the subscription and I need to integrate monthly based subscription in PayPal